# SparkFun USB UART Breakout (CY7C65213) board burning

Tags: usb, uart, firmware, breakout, sparkfun

I have been using the SparkFun USB UART Breakout (CY7C65213) board for flashing firmware to boards. But it is always burning up the Microcontroller and ruining the boards after a about 30-40 writes. I was wondering if these boards are not for prolonged use?

Comment: Check RXD and TXD logic high voltage and compare to target VDD. Maybe your RXD/TXD voltage high is 5V and target VDD is 3V3, if target ports are 5V tolerant (have input diodes to VDD and GND) they will survive (if injected current is low enough), if they are not 5V tolerant they will probably burn

Comment: From SParkfun: "a VIO selection jumper, a low-voltage selection jumper, and a multitude of pins that allow you to utilize the board to its fullest potential. The CY7C65213 breakout is capable of operating at **both 3V and 5V** based on what the VIO selection jumper is set to. Additionally this breakout can operate at 2V and below."

Comment: "I was wondering if these boards are not for prolonged use" -- that's not likely.  Something else is going wrong.  What boards are you breaking?

Comment: You don't tell any details to make any guesses why boards burn up. They may be incompatible or you may be using them in a way that makes them burn, such as having an ungroundes power supply with a lot of leakage turned on before connecting.

Comment: @MakePlatanGreatAgain you were right. Thanks! The target ports were not 5V tolerant and I had to solder the  3V junction in order to not burn the uart board. It’s working all good now